# Insert the user name when inserting new row using macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I would like to insert the user name of the 'creator' (person who inserts) new row. I want the user name entered in column G.

I currently have the following macro to insert the row:

```
Sub Insert_Row()
Dim rActive As Range

Set rActive = ActiveCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
   .EntireRow.Copy
    With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End With

rActive.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So what's the problem? User is not a problem, `Environ("Username")`.

Comment: I would like to have the users name inserted into column G of the new row so as to show who created the entry. I know i will need to incorporate the Environ("Username") but how do I do this based on the insert row action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to track the inserted row and set column G to the username, like this:

```
Sub Insert_Row()
Dim rActive As Range
Dim insertRow As Long
Set rActive = ActiveCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
   insertRow = .Row + 1
   .EntireRow.Copy
    With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End With
Cells(insertRow, "G").Value = Environ("Username")
rActive.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.